# Closing a Vue.js component on click

Tags: vue.js, components

I'm currently working on a small project, but I'm stuck and can't find the correct answer that I'm looking for so maybe someone can help me out here.

So what i have are 2 components where the parent component calls the child component like so:

```
<open-pokemon
        v-if="open"
        :pokemon-name="clickedPokemon"
        :type="clickedPokemonType"
        >
</open-pokemon>
```

The openPokemon component also got a closing button to close the component what I want to do is to delete the component from the dom, but it still needs to be rendered when the openPokemon gets called again.

Anyway here is the closing method:

```
closePokemon: function (e) {
            document.getElementById(e).classList.add('close');
            self = this;
            self.$destroy();
            self.$el.parentNode.removeChild(self.$el);
        }
```

And here is my html for that:

```
<div id="pokemon-single" class="c-pokemon__single-open" :class="type">
                    <div class="flex justify-end">
                        <button @click="closePokemon('pokemon-single')" class="c-pokemon__single-close">
                            X
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

While this will work i can't seem to figure out why I can't rerender the component when i call it again in the parent component. Any help would be appreciated. If you need more information let me know.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why not simply set the `open` property, the one used by `v-if`, to false?

Comment: Please do not use vanilla JS (`classList`, `removeChild` etc...) while using Vue. Use the state to trigger things in your DOM.

Comment: So emit the button press to the parent, and in the parent's response to the emit, change the `open` property to false.

Comment: I will avoid it @kissu

Comment: Thanks I upvoted your reply, but marked the answer down below @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: I'm glad that you got an answer, but you are asking about some of the most basic and rudimentary concepts of use of Vue js, suggesting that you may benefit by reviewing a tutorial or two for future guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

- Emit a `close` event from the child when the close button is clicked.
- Listen for the close event in the parent and set `open` to false.

#### Child (OpenPokemon)

```html
<template>
  <div id="pokemon-single" class="c-pokemon__single-open" :class="type">
    <div class="flex justify-end">
      <button @click="close" class="c-pokemon__single-close">X</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    close () {
      this.$emit('close')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

#### Parent

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <open-pokemon
      v-if="open"
      :pokemon-name="clickedPokemon"
      :type="clickedPokemonType"
      @close="open = false"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks indeed i had to emit `close` and listen for it in the parent!